# Xcode audio player suddenly stops working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

My app plays previewURLs of songs from Spotify. After messing with my devices sound settings to connect my bluetooth headphones, my xcode app suddenly started giving me a list of errors when trying to play a song. I know it has to be because of a settings issue because when my teammate runs the app it plays songs just fine. Here are the errors I get:

```
2020-04-19 14:42:54.178671-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  HALDefaultDevice::Initialize: couldn't add the default input device listener, Error: 1102 ()
2020-04-19 14:42:54.180684-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  HALDefaultDevice::Initialize: couldn't add the default output device listener, Error: 1102 ()
2020-04-19 14:42:54.181832-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  HALDefaultDevice::Initialize: couldn't add the default system output device listener, Error: 1102 ()
2020-04-19 14:42:54.183826-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  HALDefaultDevice::Initialize: couldn't add the default shared output device listener, Error: 1102 ()
2020-04-19 14:42:54.188086-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000398c720> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-04-19 14:42:54.190253-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  AudioObjectSetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
2020-04-19 14:42:54.190642-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] AudioSessionSimulatorClientManager.cpp:83:SimulatorUpdateHALForPrimaySession_Priv: Failed to set processVolumeScalar on device. Error: 560947818
2020-04-19 14:42:54.902449-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376]  HALCADClient::GetPropertyData: unknown property
2020-04-19 14:42:54.902598-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:776   couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2020-04-19 14:42:54.902983-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376]  HALCADClient::GetPropertyData: unknown property
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903132-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:776   couldn't get default output device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903415-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903646-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903813-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376] CA_UISoundClient.cpp:110:CA_UISoundClientBase: * * * NULL AQIONode object
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903850-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2020-04-19 14:42:54.903973-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
2020-04-19 14:42:54.904010-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7268376] CA_UISoundClient.cpp:772:UISoundNewRenderer: Can't make UISound Renderer
2020-04-19 14:42:54.904105-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] [AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1765:Prime: failed (-66680); will stop (11025/0 frames)
2020-04-19 14:42:54.904904-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2020-04-19 14:42:54.905060-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
2020-04-19 14:42:54.916099-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7265197] [AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1765:Prime: failed (-66680); will stop (11025/0 frames)
2020-04-19 14:42:57.367873-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2020-04-19 14:42:57.368232-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
2020-04-19 14:42:57.368428-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028] [AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1765:Prime: failed (-66680); will stop (11025/0 frames)
2020-04-19 14:42:58.357297-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2020-04-19 14:42:58.357749-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
2020-04-19 14:42:58.358055-0700 bauxloginpage[78388:7264028] [AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1765:Prime: failed (-66680); will stop (11025/0 frames)
```

Comment: In my settings for sound effects, output, and input I have the option to play it through internal speakers or desktop streaming audio device

Comment: In the device simulator going to the hardware tab and erasing all content and settings fixed the issue.

Comment: If you're testing this in iOS14 simulator from Xcode11beta3(or below) then you may be hitting this bug 'AVPlayer not working with iOS 14 beta': https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650741

Answer (score 1):

You can:

Clean Xcode build folder (cmd-shift-k)

Restart Xcode. (Quit the app)

Try your app on different devices. Such as your phone or a different simulator device.

If the problem still happens, comment

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue after upgrading to XCode 12.2 (Big Sur).
Line of code is:

```
OSStatus status = AudioQueueSetProperty(audioQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentDevice, &deviceUID, sizeof(audioDeviceUID));
err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
```

Error is:

```
[AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1904:Prime: failed (-66680); will stop (66150/0 frames)
```